# Object constructors functions

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Good day, I just want to make sure that I got the idea right with the object constructors functions

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.admin = false;
}

let userOne = new User("jack");
console.log(userOne);

this.name = name -> means that every newly created object using the new will have different names based on what I enter.
this.admin = false -> will be in all the newly created object because i set it's value into false.
```

For example if I enter `this.age = 26,` the age will also be 26 in all the newly created objects.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly.